# Transfer files using lftp in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, centos

I have server A `test-lx`, and server B `test2-lx`, I want to transfer files from server A to server B.
While transfering the files i'll need to create a driectory only if it's not exist, how can i check if a directory exist during the lftp conenction? How can i out several files in one command instead of doing this in 2 lines.
Is there an option to use `find -maxdepth 1 -name DirName`

Here is my code:

```
lftp -u drop-up,1Q2w3e4R   ftp://ta1bbn01:21 << EOF

cd $desFolder
mkdir test
cd test
put $srcFil
put $srcFile

bye 
EOF
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simple way with ftp:

```
#!/bin/bash

ftp -inv ip << EOF
user username password

cd /home/xxx/xxx/what/you/want/
put what_you_want_to_upload

bye
EOF
```

With lftp:

```
#!/bin/bash

lftp -u username,password ip << EOF

cd /home/xxx/xxx/what/you/want/
put what_you_want_to_upload

bye
EOF
```

From lftp manual:

```
-u <user>[,<pass>]  use the user/password for authentication
```

You can use mkdir for create a directory. And you can use put command several time like this:

```
put what_you_want_to_upload
put what_you_want_to_upload2
put what_you_want_to_upload3
```

And you can close connection with `bye`

---

You can check folder is exist or not like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
checkfolder=$(lftp -c "open -u user,pass ip; ls /home/test1/test1231")

if [ "$checkfolder" == "" ];
then
echo "folder does not exist"
else
echo "folder exist"
fi
```

From lftp manual:

```
-c <cmd>            execute the commands and exit
```

And you can open another connection for put some files.

---

I don't know how to check folder is exist or not with one connection, but I can do that like this. Maybe you can find better solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
checkfolder=$(lftp -c "open -u user,pass ip; ls /home/test1/test2")

if [ "$checkfolder" == "" ];
then

lftp -u user,pass ip << EOF

mkdir test2
cd test2
put testfile.txt
bye
EOF

else

echo "The directory already exists - exiting"

fi
```

Comment: If i'm running this via the terminal its working, but in the bash script it's not working it's making the connection but it's not executing the `put` and the `cd` command.
This is the command that i'm using to establish a connection:
`lftp -u myUser,myPass   ftp://ta1bbn01:21 SwDrop\Repository`
`sleep 5
cd $desFolder
sleep 5
put $srcFile
bye`

Comment: Actually it worked now, do you know how can i use conditions in the opened connection ? 
I want to check if the folder that i want to create is already exists.
This is what i wrote :
`lftp -u drop-up,1Q2w3e4R   ftp://ta1bbn01:21 << EOF

cd $desFolder

if [ ! -d /test ]; then
 mkdir test
 cd test
 put $srcFile
else
 echo "The directory already exists -  exiting"
fi
 


bye 
EOF`

Comment: You can't use if, because it is not ftp command. You can use only ftp commands after opening ftp connection. You can check folder is exist or not with another connection. Can you explain what do you want, please edit your question.

Comment: The command `ls` return a string even if a directory doesn't exist.
This is the string that i got: `550 /MSP-3.0.0.0: No such file or directory`

Comment: So you can check if return this or not.

Comment: I'll do that but it's not so efficient, thanks anyway.

Comment: I've found a way to make the `find ` command work.
`find -d 1 DirToSearch`

Comment: When you are in lftp commands, "cd" refers to remote dir, not local dir. You have to use "!cd" for local dir.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same basic coding outline as phe however I found that using ls /foldername will output "folder does not exist" if the folder is empty. To solve this I use

```
#!/bin/bash
checkfolder=$(lftp -c "open -u user,pass ip; ls | grep /test1231")

if [ "$checkfolder" == "" ];
then
echo "folder does not exist"
else
echo "folder exists"
fi
```

Please note this only works if the folder is in the root directory. For sub directories in a folder the following should work.

```
#!/bin/bash
checkfolder=$(lftp -c "open -u user,pass ip; find | grep home/test1/test1231")

if [ "$checkfolder" == "" ];
then
echo "folder does not exist"
else
echo "folder exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

First prepare credentials record into ~/.netrc file as:

```
machine site-url-here
login user-login-here
password user-password-here
```

so you don't have to expose your password on the command line to use this in script.

Then call:

```
lftp -e "lftp-command-here" ftps://user-login-here@site-url-here/initial-folder-here/`
```

In my case I run `mget -c *` lftp command for getting all logs from java spring boot application running linux app instance at azure infrastructure.
Of course you can put your commands separated by semicolon there.